# How to use the new Material Design Icon themes: Outlined, Rounded, Two-Tone and Sharp?

Tags: icons, material-design, google-material-icons

Google has revamped its [Material Design Icons](https://material.io/tools/icons/?style=baseline) with 4 new preset themes:

**Outlined, Rounded, Two-Tone and Sharp**, in addition to the regular **Filled/Baseline** theme:

---

*But, unfortunately, it doesn't say anywhere how to use the new themes.*

---

I've been [using it via Google Web Fonts](https://google.github.io/material-design-icons/#icon-font-for-the-web) by including the link:

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
```

And then using the required icon [as suggested in the documentation](https://google.github.io/material-design-icons/#using-the-icons-in-html):

```html
<i class="material-icons">account_balance</i>
```

But it always shows the 'Filled/Baseline' version.

---

I've tried doing the following to use the **Outlined** theme instead:

```html
<i class="material-icons">account_balance_outlined</i>
<i class="material-icons material-icons-outlined">account_balance</i>
```

and, changing the Web Fonts link to:

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons&style=outlined" rel="stylesheet">
```

etc. But it doesn't work.

---

*And there's no point in taking shots in the dark like that.*

---

**tl;dr: Has anyone tried using the new themes? Does it even work like the baseline version (inline html tag)? Or, is it only meant to be downloaded as SVG or PNG formats?**

Comment: Does anyone know how to use the two-tone version in flutter?

Answer (score 401, accepted):

### Update (31/03/2019) : All icon themes work via Google Web Fonts now.

As pointed out by Edric, it's just a matter of adding the google web fonts link in your document's head now, like so:

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Material+Icons|Material+Icons+Outlined|Material+Icons+Two+Tone|Material+Icons+Round|Material+Icons+Sharp" rel="stylesheet">
```

And then adding the correct class to output the icon of a particular theme.

```html
<i class="material-icons">donut_small</i>
<i class="material-icons-outlined">donut_small</i>
<i class="material-icons-two-tone">donut_small</i>
<i class="material-icons-round">donut_small</i>
<i class="material-icons-sharp">donut_small</i>
```

The color of the icons can be changed using CSS as well.

Note: the Two-tone theme icons are a bit glitchy at present.

---

### Update (14/11/2018) : List of 16 outline icons that work with the "_outline" suffix.

Here's the most recent list of 16 outline icons that work with the regular Material-icons Webfont, using the **_outline** suffix (tested and confirmed).

(As found on the [material-design-icons github page](https://github.com/google/material-design-icons/find/master). Search for: "**_outline_24px.svg**")

```html
<i class="material-icons">help_outline</i>
<i class="material-icons">label_outline</i>
<i class="material-icons">mail_outline</i>
<i class="material-icons">info_outline</i>
<i class="material-icons">lock_outline</i>
<i class="material-icons">lightbulb_outline</i>
<i class="material-icons">play_circle_outline</i>
<i class="material-icons">error_outline</i>
<i class="material-icons">add_circle_outline</i>
<i class="material-icons">people_outline</i>
<i class="material-icons">person_outline</i>
<i class="material-icons">pause_circle_outline</i>
<i class="material-icons">chat_bubble_outline</i>
<i class="material-icons">remove_circle_outline</i>
<i class="material-icons">check_box_outline_blank</i>
<i class="material-icons">pie_chart_outlined</i>
```

Note that *pie_chart* needs to be "*pie_chart_**outlined***" and not *outline*.

---

### This is a hack to test out the new icon themes using an inline tag. It's not the official solution.

As of today (July 19, 2018), a little over 2 months since the new icons themes were introduced, **there is No Way** to include these icons using an inline tag `<i class="material-icons"></i>`.

[+Martin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50364649/7364168) has pointed out that there's an issue raised on Github regarding the same: https://github.com/google/material-design-icons/issues/773

So, until Google comes up with a solution for this, I've started using a hack to include these new icon themes in my **development environment** before downloading the appropriate icons as SVG or PNG. And I thought I'd share it with you all.

---

**IMPORTANT**: Do not use this on a production environment as each of the included CSS files from Google are over 1MB in size.

---

Google uses these stylesheets to showcase the icons on their demo page:

**Outline:**

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://storage.googleapis.com/non-spec-apps/mio-icons/latest/outline.css">
```

**Rounded:**

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://storage.googleapis.com/non-spec-apps/mio-icons/latest/round.css">
```

**Two-Tone:**

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://storage.googleapis.com/non-spec-apps/mio-icons/latest/twotone.css">
```

**Sharp:**

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://storage.googleapis.com/non-spec-apps/mio-icons/latest/sharp.css">
```

Each of these files contain the icons of the respective themes included as background-images (Base64 image-data). And here's how we can use this to test out the compatibility of a particular icon in our design before downloading it for use in the production environment.

---

**STEP 1**:

Include the stylesheet of the theme that you want to use.
Eg: For the 'Outlined' theme, use the stylesheet for 'outline.css'

**STEP 2**:

Add the following classes to your **own** stylesheet:

```css
.material-icons-new {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 24px;
    height: 24px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: contain;
}

.icon-white {
    webkit-filter: contrast(4) invert(1);
    -moz-filter: contrast(4) invert(1);
    -o-filter: contrast(4) invert(1);
    -ms-filter: contrast(4) invert(1);
    filter: contrast(4) invert(1);
}
```

**STEP 3**:

Use the icon by adding the following **classes** to the `<i>` tag:

1. `material-icons-new` class
2. Icon name as shown on the material icons demo page, prefixed with the theme name followed by a hyphen.

*Prefixes:*

Outlined: `outline-`

Rounded: `round-`

Two-Tone: `twotone-`

Sharp: `sharp-`

*Eg (for 'announcement' icon):*

`outline-announcement`, `round-announcement`, `twotone-announcement`, `sharp-announcement`

*3) Use an optional 3rd class `icon-white` for inverting the color from black to white (for dark backgrounds)*

---

**Changing icon size:**

Since this is a background-image and not a font-icon, use the `height` and `width` properties of CSS to modify the size of the icons. The default is set to 24px in the `material-icons-new` class.

---

**Example:**

**Case I:** For the **Outlined** Theme of the **account_circle** icon:

1. Include the stylesheet:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://storage.googleapis.com/non-spec-apps/mio-icons/latest/outline.css">
```

2. Add the icon tag on your page:

```html
<i class="material-icons-new outline-account_circle"></i>
```

*Optional (For dark backgrounds):*

```html
<i class="material-icons-new outline-account_circle icon-white"></i>
```

---

**Case II:** For the **Sharp** Theme of the **assessment** icon:

1. Include the stylesheet:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://storage.googleapis.com/non-spec-apps/mio-icons/latest/sharp.css">
```

2. Add the icon tag on your page:

```html
<i class="material-icons-new sharp-assessment"></i>
```

*(For dark backgrounds):*

```html
<i class="material-icons-new sharp-assessment icon-white"></i>
```

---

I can't stress enough that this is NOT THE RIGHT WAY to include the icons on your production environment. But if you have to scan through multiple icons on your in-development page, it does make the icon inclusion pretty easy and saves a lot of time.

Downloading the icon as SVG or PNG sure is a better option when it comes to site-speed optimization, but font-icons are a time-saver when it comes to the prototyping phase and checking if a particular icon goes with your design, etc.

---

**I will update this post if and when Google comes up with a solution for this issue that does not involve downloading an icon for usage.**

Comment: hello! this is quite useful, but I still not able to include my icon, I want to include screen_share, I tried with the class .outline-screen_share but it does print anything, I chekc the class in the inspector and it exists, may I lost any step?

Comment: @cucuru Thanks, I think you missed **Step 2**. Adding the class `.material-icons-new` and its properties to your own stylesheet first and then calling the icon by `<i class="material-icons-new outline-screen_share"></i>`.

Comment: There now seems to be new CSS fonts for the new Material Icon themes: https://codepen.io/Chan4077/pen/bZNyQG

Comment: For Angular Material, you need to use `fontSet` instead of `class`. See Ron Netzer's answer below from 8/14/19.

Comment: Does google material icons render smartly or it renders the entire file?

Comment: I believe it's different again and your latest answer edit is irrelevant. Take [warning](https://fonts.google.com/icons?icon.query=warning&icon.style=Outlined) for example, the class `material-icons-outlined` doesn't work. You'll need to add a new import, then use a new class

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Material+Symbols+Outlined:opsz,wght,FILL,GRAD@20..48,100..700,0..1,-50..200" />
```

Then enables the class `material-symbols-outlined` for
```html
<mat-icon class="material-symbols-outlined">warning</mat-icon>
```

Answer (score 57):

For angular material you should use fontSet input to change the font family:

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Material+Icons|Material+Icons+Outlined|Material+Icons+Two+Tone|Material+Icons+Round|Material+Icons+Sharp"
rel="stylesheet" />

<mat-icon>edit</mat-icon>
<mat-icon fontSet="material-icons-outlined">edit</mat-icon>
<mat-icon fontSet="material-icons-two-tone">edit</mat-icon>
...
```

Comment: This is the correct answer, just confirmed it for later `Angular v10`.

Comment: What are the possible values for `fontSet` by the way?

Comment: @Junaid material-icons-outlined, material-icons-two-tone, material-icons-round, material-icons-sharp

Answer (score 39):

As of 27 February 2019, there are CSS fonts for the new Material Icon themes.

However, you have to create CSS classes to use the fonts.

The font families are as follows:

- `Material Icons Outlined` - Outlined icons
- `Material Icons Two Tone` - Two-tone icons
- `Material Icons Round` - Rounded icons
- `Material Icons Sharp` - Sharp icons

See the code sample below for an example:

```css
body {
  font-family: Roboto, sans-serif;
}

.material-icons-outlined,
.material-icons.material-icons--outlined,
.material-icons-two-tone,
.material-icons.material-icons--two-tone,
.material-icons-round,
.material-icons.material-icons--round,
.material-icons-sharp,
.material-icons.material-icons--sharp {
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
  font-size: 24px;
  line-height: 1;
  letter-spacing: normal;
  text-transform: none;
  display: inline-block;
  white-space: nowrap;
  word-wrap: normal;
  direction: ltr;
  -webkit-font-feature-settings: 'liga';
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}

.material-icons-outlined,
.material-icons.material-icons--outlined {
  font-family: 'Material Icons Outlined';
}

.material-icons-two-tone,
.material-icons.material-icons--two-tone {
  font-family: 'Material Icons Two Tone';
}

.material-icons-round,
.material-icons.material-icons--round {
  font-family: 'Material Icons Round';
}

.material-icons-sharp,
.material-icons.material-icons--sharp {
  font-family: 'Material Icons Sharp';
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500|Material+Icons|Material+Icons+Outlined|Material+Icons+Two+Tone|Material+Icons+Round|Material+Icons+Sharp">
</head>

<body>
  <section id="original">
    <h2>Baseline</h2>
    <i class="material-icons">home</i>
    <i class="material-icons">assignment</i>
  </section>
  <section id="outlined">
    <h2>Outlined</h2>
    <i class="material-icons-outlined">home</i>
    <i class="material-icons material-icons--outlined">assignment</i>
  </section>
  <section id="two-tone">
    <h2>Two tone</h2>
    <i class="material-icons-two-tone">home</i>
    <i class="material-icons material-icons--two-tone">assignment</i>
  </section>
  <section id="rounded">
    <h2>Rounded</h2>
    <i class="material-icons-round">home</i>
    <i class="material-icons material-icons--round">assignment</i>
  </section>
  <section id="sharp">
    <h2>Sharp</h2>
    <i class="material-icons-sharp">home</i>
    <i class="material-icons material-icons--sharp">assignment</i>
  </section>
</body>

</html>
```

Or view it on [Codepen](https://codepen.io/Chan4077/pen/bZNyQG)

---

EDIT: As of 10 March 2019, it appears that there are now classes for the new font icons:

```css
body {
  font-family: Roboto, sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500|Material+Icons|Material+Icons+Outlined|Material+Icons+Two+Tone|Material+Icons+Round|Material+Icons+Sharp">
</head>

<body>
  <section id="original">
    <h2>Baseline</h2>
    <i class="material-icons">home</i>
    <i class="material-icons">assignment</i>
  </section>
  <section id="outlined">
    <h2>Outlined</h2>
    <i class="material-icons-outlined">home</i>
    <i class="material-icons-outlined">assignment</i>
  </section>
  <section id="two-tone">
    <h2>Two tone</h2>
    <i class="material-icons-two-tone">home</i>
    <i class="material-icons-two-tone">assignment</i>
  </section>
  <section id="rounded">
    <h2>Rounded</h2>
    <i class="material-icons-round">home</i>
    <i class="material-icons-round">assignment</i>
  </section>
  <section id="sharp">
    <h2>Sharp</h2>
    <i class="material-icons-sharp">home</i>
    <i class="material-icons-sharp">assignment</i>
  </section>
</body>

</html>
```

EDIT #2: Here's a workaround to tint two-tone icons by using [CSS image filters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/filter) (code adapted from [this comment](https://github.com/google/material-design-icons/issues/773#issuecomment-485631848)):

```css
body {
  font-family: Roboto, sans-serif;
}

.material-icons-two-tone {
  filter: invert(0.5) sepia(1) saturate(10) hue-rotate(180deg);
  font-size: 48px;
}

.material-icons,
.material-icons-outlined,
.material-icons-round,
.material-icons-sharp {
  color: #0099ff;
  font-size: 48px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500|Material+Icons|Material+Icons+Outlined|Material+Icons+Two+Tone|Material+Icons+Round|Material+Icons+Sharp">
</head>

<body>
  <section id="original">
    <h2>Baseline</h2>
    <i class="material-icons">home</i>
    <i class="material-icons">assignment</i>
  </section>
  <section id="outlined">
    <h2>Outlined</h2>
    <i class="material-icons-outlined">home</i>
    <i class="material-icons-outlined">assignment</i>
  </section>
  <section id="two-tone">
    <h2>Two tone</h2>
    <i class="material-icons-two-tone">home</i>
    <i class="material-icons-two-tone">assignment</i>
  </section>
  <section id="rounded">
    <h2>Rounded</h2>
    <i class="material-icons-round">home</i>
    <i class="material-icons-round">assignment</i>
  </section>
  <section id="sharp">
    <h2>Sharp</h2>
    <i class="material-icons-sharp">home</i>
    <i class="material-icons-sharp">assignment</i>
  </section>
</body>

</html>
```

Or view it on [Codepen](https://codepen.io/sphism/pen/xeaGPW)

Comment: It appears that the `color` CSS attribute currently doesn't affect the colour of the new Material Icon themes.

Comment: The outlined icon is not working on ie ?, any thoughts ?

Comment: it doesn't show up at all, even if you run this page on ie, you can see that it is just blank space,  i ended up using baseline on ie!

Comment: It appears that the `color` property is supported on all icons except the two-tone icons. (Tested as of today)

Answer (score 29):

## As of 12/05/2020, You need to

**1. include CSS:**

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Material+Icons|Material+Icons+Outlined|Material+Icons+Two+Tone|Material+Icons+Round|Material+Icons+Sharp" rel="stylesheet">
```

**2. Use it like this:**

```
<i class="material-icons">account_balance</i>
<i class="material-icons material-icons-outlined">account_balance</i>
<i class="material-icons material-icons-two-tone">account_balance</i>
<i class="material-icons material-icons-sharp">account_balance</i>
<i class="material-icons material-icons-round">account_balance</i>
```

Note: For example, to use outlined style, You need to specify *material-icons* **AND** *material-icons-outlined* classes.

Comment: For Angular, use `<mat-icon class="material-icons-two-tone">alarm</mat-icon>`. Replace the class with either `material-icons`, `material-icons-outlined`, `material-icons-two-tone`, `material-icons-sharp` or `material-icons-round`. And replace the alarm with any icon name from: https://material.io/resources/icons/?icon=assessment&style=baseline

Comment: Using mat-icon means, you are adding additional module, which increases app size (Well, it increases little bit, but sometimes a few kb is important)

Comment: @VanoMaisuradze can you link to the doc?

Comment: AFAIK, there is no doc for this.

Answer (score 15):

If you already have *material-icons* working in your web project, just need to update your reference in the html file and the used class for icons:

**html reference:**

Before

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet" />
```

After

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Material+Icons|Material+Icons+Outlined|Material+Icons+Two+Tone|Material+Icons+Round|Material+Icons+Sharp"
rel="stylesheet" />
```

**material icons class:**

After that just check wich className are you using:

Before:

```
<i className="material-icons">weekend</i>
```

After:

```
<i className="material-icons-outlined">weekend</i>
```

that works for me... Pura vida!

Answer (score 12):

What worked for me is using *_outline* not *_outline**d*** after the icon name.

```
<mat-icon>info</mat-icon>
```

vs

```
<mat-icon>info_outline</mat-icon>
```

Comment: Ah-hah, so it works that way on Angular; that's pretty neat.

Comment: there are some icons that are outlines and has the suffix _outline. It only works for those

Comment: @SangminLee yes, this is the list of icons where it should work. https://material.io/tools/icons/?style=outline

Comment: @Aj334 yes it is neat, also can you accept this answer if it answered your question?

Comment: @fxrxz Sorry man, not really the answer I was looking for. This may work on Angular, but for the rest of us who are using it via Google Web Fonts, there isn't a solution out there yet.

Comment: I just used this with the plain Material web font in a React.js project. So it doesn't have anything to do with Angular. I think this is the solution.

Comment: @Juuro. Actually, that only works with 16 icons as of today. info_outline included. I've updated my answer with a list of icons the "_outline" suffix works with.

Answer (score 8):

#### The webfonts link works now, in all browsers!

Simply add your themes to the font link separated by a pipe (`|`), like this

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons|Material+Icons+Outlined" rel="stylesheet">
```

Then reference the class, like this:

```html
// class="material-icons" or class="material-icons-outlined"

<i class="material-icons">account_balance</i>
<i class="material-icons-outlined">account_balance</i>
```

This pattern will also work with Angular Material:

```html
<mat-icon>account_balance</mat-icon>
<mat-icon class="material-icons-outlined">account_balance</mat-icon>
```

Comment: I will keep this simple approach until the attribute solution comes out. Good one @intergalactic

Comment: What if I get the icons via `dependencies` in package.json of the app instead of `<link>`? I don't get to include outlined icons in the URL...

Comment: this is the way to go when using mat-icon

Answer (score 6):

None of the answers so far explains how to download the various variants of that font so that you can serve them from your own website (WWW server).

While this might seem like a minor issue from the technical perspective, it is a big issue from the legal perspective, at least if you intend to present your pages to any EU citizen (or even, if you do that by accident). This is even true for companies which reside in the US (or any country outside the EU).

If anybody is interested why this is, I'll update this answer and give some more details here, but at the moment, I don't want to waste too much space off-topic.

**Having said this:**

I've downloaded all versions (regular, outlined, rounded, sharp, two-tone) of that font following two very easy steps (it was @Aj334's answer to his own question which put me on the right track) (example: "outlined" variant):

1. Get the CSS from the Google CDN by *directly letting your browser
   fetch the CSS URL*, i.e. copy the following URL into your browser's
   location bar:

   ```
   https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Material+Icons+Outlined
   ```

   This will return a page which looks like this (at least in Firefox 70.0.1 at the time of writing this):

   ```
   /* fallback */
   @font-face {
     font-family: 'Material Icons Outlined';
     font-style: normal;
     font-weight: 400;
     src: url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/materialiconsoutlined/v14/gok-H7zzDkdnRel8-DQ6KAXJ69wP1tGnf4ZGhUce.woff2) format('woff2');
   }

   .material-icons-outlined {
     font-family: 'Material Icons Outlined';
     font-weight: normal;
     font-style: normal;
     font-size: 24px;
     line-height: 1;
     letter-spacing: normal;
     text-transform: none;
     display: inline-block;
     white-space: nowrap;
     word-wrap: normal;
     direction: ltr;
     -moz-font-feature-settings: 'liga';
     -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
   }
   ```
2. Find the line starting with `src:` in the above code, and *let your browser fetch the URL contained in that line*, i.e. copy the following URL into your browser's location bar:

   ```
   https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/materialiconsoutlined/v14/gok-H7zzDkdnRel8-DQ6KAXJ69wP1tGnf4ZGhUce.woff2
   ```

   Now the browser will download that `.woff2` file and offer to save it locally (at least, Firefox did).

Two final remarks:

Of course, you can download the other variants of that font using the same method. In the first step, just replace the character sequence `Outlined` in the URL by the character sequences `Round` (yes, really, although [here](https://material.io/resources/icons/) it's called "Rounded" in the left navigation menu), `Sharp` or `Two+Tone`, respectively. The result page will look nearly the same each time, but the URL in the `src:` line of course is different for each variant.

Finally, in step 1, you even can use that URL:

```
https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Material+Icons|Material+Icons+Outlined|Material+Icons+Two+Tone|Material+Icons+Round|Material+Icons+Sharp
```

This will return the CSS for all variants in one page, which then contains five `src:` lines, each one with another URL designating where the respective font is located.

Answer (score 5):

New themes are probably not (yet?) part of the Material Icons font. [Link](https://github.com/google/material-design-icons/issues/773).

Comment: That project hasn't published a release in 2 years, I'm not holding my breath.

Answer (score 4):

The Aj334's recent edit works perfectly.

#### google CDN

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Material+Icons|Material+Icons+Outlined|Material+Icons+Two+Tone|Material+Icons+Round|Material+Icons+Sharp" rel="stylesheet">
```

#### Icon Element

```
<i class="material-icons">donut_small</i>
<i class="material-icons-outlined">donut_small</i>
<i class="material-icons-two-tone">donut_small</i>
<i class="material-icons-round">donut_small</i>
<i class="material-icons-sharp">donut_small</i>
```

Comment: It is working in angular as well, 
i.e : <mat-icon class="material-icons-outlined">sell</mat-icon>

Answer (score 2):

I was unsatisfied that until know Google hasn't yet released their new designs as font or svg icon set. Therefore I put together a small npm package to solve the problem.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/ts-material-icons-svg

Simply import the icons you wanna use and add them to your registry. This also supports tree shaking since only those icons are added to your project that you really want and/or need.

```
npm i --save https://github.com/MarcusCalidus/ts-material-icons-svg.git
```

to use two tone icons for example

```
import {icon_edit} from 'ts-material-icons-svg/dist/twotone';

matIconRegistry.addSvgIcon(
            'edit',
            domSanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(icon_edit),
        );
```

In your html template you now can use the new icon

```
<mat-icon svgIcon="edit"></mat-icon>
```

Answer (score 1):

Put in head link to google styles

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons+Outlined" rel="stylesheet">
```

and in body something like this

```
<i class="material-icons-outlined">bookmarks</i>
```

Answer (score 1):

**Setting up the Two-tone color:**

As described above you can use the `color` css key except for materials [Two-tone](https://material.io/resources/icons/?search=comment&icon=add_comment&style=twotone) theme which seems to be glitchy ;-)

A workaround is described in one of several angular material github [issue](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-web-react/issues/730)'s by using a custom css filter. This custom filter can be generated [here](https://codepen.io/sosuke/pen/Pjoqqp).

E.g.:

Html:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Material+Icons|Material+Icons+Outlined|Material+Icons+Round|Material+Icons+Two+Tone|Material+Icons+Sharp">

<i class="material-icons-two-tone red">home</i>
```

css:

```
.red {
filter: invert(8%) sepia(94%) saturate(4590%) hue-rotate(358deg) brightness(101%) contrast(112%);
}
```

Attachments:

- Working Angular [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-icon-afckgh?file=index.html)
- [Codepen example](https://codepen.io/themau5/pen/QWwaYKR)
- [Codepen CSS filter Generator](https://codepen.io/sosuke/pen/Pjoqqp)

Answer (score 1):

### For Angular users (tested on v14):

If you want to change the globally used theme of icons to e.g. `outlined`, you can do this in your `AppModule` or wherever you need it:

```
export class AppModule {
  constructor(private readonly iconRegistry: MatIconRegistry) {
    const defaultFontSetClasses = iconRegistry.getDefaultFontSetClass();
    const outlinedFontSetClasses = defaultFontSetClasses
      .filter(fontSetClass => fontSetClass !== 'material-icons')
      .concat(['material-icons-outlined']);
    iconRegistry.setDefaultFontSetClass(...outlinedFontSetClasses);
  }
}
```

`defaultFontSetClasses` also includes `mat-ligature-font` class name, which you need to keep in order to render the icons properly if you're using `[fontIcon]` property binding in your `<mat-icon>` elements.

also, remember to load the `Material Icons Outlined` stylesheet:

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons|Material+Icons+Outlined" rel="stylesheet" />
```

per https://material.angular.io/components/icon/api#MatIconRegistry

Comment: When I try this method it fails with: ts2339 property 'filter' does not exist on type 'string'

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using IcoMoon app to create a custom font using only the new themed icons I required for a recent web app build. It's not perfect but you can mimic the existing Google Font functionality pretty nicely with a little bit of setup. Here's a writeup:

https://medium.com/@leemartin/how-to-use-material-icon-outlined-rounded-two-tone-and-sharp-themes-92276f2415d2

If someone is feeling daring, they could convert the entire theme using IcoMoon. Hell, IcoMoon probably has an internal process that would make it easy since they already have the original Material Icons set in their library.

Anyway, this isn't a perfect solution, but it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Somewhat hilariously, Google has made a font that works correctly in Safari but not in Chrome. Here's the https://codepen.io/anon/pen/zbavza

```
<i class="material-icons-round red">warning</i>
```

[image: red round warning material icon in safari]

In reference to https://stackoverflow.com/a/54902967/4740291 and not being able to change the color using css.