# How can I get Angular Material Icon to show the outline in my Angular app?

Tags: angular, angular-material

I currently have

```
<mat-icon>info<mat-icon>
```

which gives the output of the info icon with the color filled. However, I just want the outline of the icon. How do I do that?

The icon I want is https://material.io/tools/icons/?icon=info&style=outline instead of https://material.io/tools/icons/?icon=info&style=baseline

Answer (score 49, accepted):

## Edit: 5/2019

This question is out of date. A more in depth, recent, answer can be found here: [How to use the new Material Design Icon themes: Outlined, Rounded, Two-Tone and Sharp?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50303454/how-to-use-the-new-material-design-icon-themes-outlined-rounded-two-tone-and)

The general idea is that some of the icons aren't imported by default, and need to be targeted from a different library.

---

### Edit: 2/2022

Quick reference to the latest import link to save clicks:

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Material+Icons|Material+Icons+Outlined|Material+Icons+Two+Tone|Material+Icons+Round|Material+Icons+Sharp" rel="stylesheet">
```

---

#### Original answer:

You're looking for `<mat-icon>info_outline</mat-icon>`.

You can use this same template for any item that has an outline image, but don't attempt to use it for objects that are the same for filled/outlined.

e.g. `<mat-icon>label</mat-icon><mat-icon>label_outline</mat-icon>`

Comment: Thank you! I was trying to prefix 'outline' to the name.

Comment: this is not working for me when the icon name has a complex name like

Comment: Also didn't work for me, specifically for edit_outline icon. Sherman's answer worked nicely though

Comment: I've voted to close this question since this is answered more in depth here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50303454/how-to-use-the-new-material-design-icon-themes-outlined-rounded-two-tone-and

Comment: The question is not out of date and the link you've provided is about using material design and has nothing to do with the angular material AFAICS.

Comment: @Skeeve the link I provided shows the exact way to import and apply the material design icons (which is what my answer above addressed previously), and it uses their new standardization. This isn't an Angular or Material specific question or answer in the end, and that linked question provides the css needed to apply it any icon (`mat-icon` or standdard `i`).

Comment: > This isn't an Angular or Material specific question
Oh, but this is. It has corresponding tags and it specifically mentions angular material in the title and in the question itself.

Comment: @Skeeve OK dude.

Comment:  this works nice. extending the href with the other font-families in index.html.
made a new answer (an extention), couldnt fit it here.

Answer (score 87):

You may include this
`|Material+Icons+Outlined`in the url to display material icon in outline.

Example:

```
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons|Material+Icons+Outlined");
```

Then in the template file, you can add in `material-icons-outlined`

```
<mat-icon class="material-icons-outlined">home</mat-icon>
```

Comment: keep scrolling..., use `fontSet`

Answer (score 46):

This is how I did it:

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons|Material+Icons+Outlined"
rel="stylesheet"/>

<mat-icon fontSet="material-icons-outlined">edit</mat-icon>
```

Found the solution [here](https://github.com/angular/components/issues/11544#issuecomment-521305891).

Answer (score 17):

Index.html

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons+Outlined" rel="stylesheet">
```

Outline all mat-icon in e.q. AppModule

```
export class AppModule { 
  constructor(iconRegistry: MatIconRegistry) {
    iconRegistry.setDefaultFontSetClass('material-icons-outlined');
  }
}
```

Comment: This is what I was looking for. Make a change in one place to quickly switch between filled and outlined.

Comment: This should be marked as answer for global setting default icon style

Answer (score 10):

There are 2 ways.

```
// 1
// "_outline"

<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">

<mat-icon>info</mat-icon>
<mat-icon>info_outlined</mat-icon> // outline work
```

```
// 2 
// "_outline" + fontSet attribute

<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Material+Icons|Material+Icons+Outlined|Material+Icons+Two+Tone|Material+Icons+Round|Material+Icons+Sharp" rel="stylesheet">

<mat-icon fontSet="material-icons-outlined">info_outlined</mat-icon> // outline work
<mat-icon fontSet="material-icons-two-tone">info</mat-icon>
<mat-icon fontSet="material-icons-round">info</mat-icon>
<mat-icon fontSet="material-icons-sharp">info</mat-icon>
```

However, not all icons have the variations in the first way. eg. `<mat-icon>home</mat-icon>` and `<mat-icon>home_outlined</mat-icon>` look the same. For those icons, the second way ("_outline" + fontSet attribute) works well.

more examples:

```
// fontSet attribute

<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Material+Icons|Material+Icons+Outlined|Material+Icons+Two+Tone|Material+Icons+Round|Material+Icons+Sharp" rel="stylesheet">

<mat-icon>home</mat-icon>
<mat-icon>home_outlined</mat-icon> // outline not work
<mat-icon fontSet="material-icons-outlined">home</mat-icon> // outline happens to work (notice: this is NOT true for all icons)

// "_outline" + fontSet attribute

<mat-icon fontSet="material-icons-outlined">home_outlined</mat-icon> // outline work, for all icons. Recommended.
<mat-icon fontSet="material-icons-two-tone">home</mat-icon>
<mat-icon fontSet="material-icons-round">home</mat-icon>
<mat-icon fontSet="material-icons-sharp">home</mat-icon>
```

Answer (score 5):

Put this in the index folder
" < link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons|Material+Icons+Outlined"
rel="stylesheet"/>"

< mat-icon fontSet="material-icons-outlined">edit

Answer (score 3):

In my opinion, the best way to do this is to inject the icon defaults.
First add the font to index.html:

```html
<link
  href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons+Outlined"
  rel="stylesheet"
/>
```

Then add the defaults to the module:

```js
providers: [
  { provide: MAT_ICON_DEFAULT_OPTIONS, useValue: { fontSet: 'material-icons-outlined' } }
]
```

With this all icons will use the outlined version.

Answer (score 1):

this is just an extention/improvement to @z.bagley's answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/50360119/16448199

replacing in index.html the old line with this extended one worked like a charm:

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Material+Icons|Material+Icons+Outlined|Material+Icons+Two+Tone|Material+Icons+Round|Material+Icons+Sharp" rel="stylesheet">
```

**Improved**

just realized after that, you can do that with the material-symbols too!
which has more format varities (except: no twotone) and has more icons to choose.
they look more logic with only 3 font-families to choose:

- rounded
- outline (which should have called 'normal')
- and sharp

and further with the attribute "fill" to choose between filled or outlined.

but instead of

```
https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Material+Symbols+Outlined:opsz,wght,FILL,GRAD@48,300,1,0|Material+Symbols+Rounded:opsz,wght,FILL,GRAD@48,400,1,0|Material+Symbols+Sharp:opsz,wght,FILL,GRAD@48,400,1,0
```

you have to use your own css, cause google css generator link is messing something up and doesnt support all variations together. this way you can even go step further and self host the fonts.

i prepared a small example: https://jsfiddle.net/apnft/tz9wugd8/
or check it here directly:

```css
.material-icons, .material-icons-outlined, .material-icons-round, 
.material-icons-sharp, .material-icons-two-tone {
  font-size: 48px !important;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'Material Symbols Outlined';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/materialsymbolsoutlined/v39/kJF1BvYX7BgnkSrUwT8OhrdQw4oELdPIeeII9v6oDMzByHX9rA6RzaxHMPdY43zj-jCxv3fzvRNU22ZXGJpEpjC_1v-p_4MrImHCIJIZrDCvHOej.woff2) format('woff2');
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'Material Symbols Rounded';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/materialsymbolsrounded/v38/syl0-zNym6YjUruM-QrEh7-nyTnjDwKNJ_190FjpZIvDmUSVOK7BDB_Qb9vUSzq3wzLK-P0J-V_Zs-QtQth3-jOcbTCVpeRL2w5rwZu2rIelXxc.woff2) format('woff2');
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'Material Symbols Sharp';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/materialsymbolssharp/v38/gNNBW2J8Roq16WD5tFNRaeLQk6-SHQ_R00k4c2_whPnoY9ruReaU4bHmz74m0ZkGH-VBYe1x0TV6x4yFH8F-H5OdzEL3sVTgJtfbYxOLojCL.woff2) format('woff2');
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'Material Symbols Outlined _Filled';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/materialsymbolsoutlined/v39/kJF1BvYX7BgnkSrUwT8OhrdQw4oELdPIeeII9v6oDMzByHX9rA6RzazHD_dY43zj-jCxv3fzvRNU22ZXGJpEpjC_1n-q_4MrImHCIJIZrDCvHOej.woff2) format('woff2');
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'Material Symbols Rounded _Filled';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/materialsymbolsrounded/v38/syl0-zNym6YjUruM-QrEh7-nyTnjDwKNJ_190FjpZIvDmUSVOK7BDJ_vb9vUSzq3wzLK-P0J-V_Zs-QtQth3-jOc7TOVpeRL2w5rwZu2rIelXxc.woff2) format('woff2');
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'Material Symbols Sharp _Filled';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/materialsymbolssharp/v38/gNNBW2J8Roq16WD5tFNRaeLQk6-SHQ_R00k4c2_whPnoY9ruReYU3rHmz74m0ZkGH-VBYe1x0TV6x4yFH8F-HxOezEL3sVTgJtfbYxOLojCL.woff2) format('woff2');
}

.material-symbols-outlined, .material-symbols-rounded, .material-symbols-sharp,
.material-symbols-outlined-filled, .material-symbols-rounded-filled, .material-symbols-sharp-filled {
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
  font-size: 48px;
  line-height: 1;
  letter-spacing: normal;
  text-transform: none;
  display: inline-block;
  white-space: nowrap;
  word-wrap: normal;
  direction: ltr;
  -moz-font-feature-settings: 'liga';
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}

.material-symbols-outlined {
  font-family: 'Material Symbols Outlined';
}

.material-symbols-rounded {
  font-family: 'Material Symbols Rounded';
}

.material-symbols-sharp {
  font-family: 'Material Symbols Sharp';
}

.material-symbols-outlined-filled {
  font-family: 'Material Symbols Outlined _Filled';
}

.material-symbols-rounded-filled {
  font-family: 'Material Symbols Rounded _Filled';
}

.material-symbols-sharp-filled {
  font-family: 'Material Symbols Sharp _Filled';
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Material+Icons|Material+Icons+Outlined|Material+Icons+Two+Tone|Material+Icons+Round|Material+Icons+Sharp" rel="stylesheet">
icons<br>normal/outlined/round/sharp/twotone
<br>
<mat-icon class="material-icons">home</mat-icon>
<mat-icon class="material-icons-outlined">home</mat-icon>
<mat-icon class="material-icons-round">home</mat-icon>
<mat-icon class="material-icons-sharp">home</mat-icon>
<mat-icon class="material-icons-two-tone">home</mat-icon>
<br>
<mat-icon class="material-icons">account_circle</mat-icon>
<mat-icon class="material-icons-outlined">account_circle</mat-icon>
<mat-icon class="material-icons-round">account_circle</mat-icon>
<mat-icon class="material-icons-sharp">account_circle</mat-icon>
<mat-icon class="material-icons-two-tone">account_circle</mat-icon>
<br>
<mat-icon class="material-icons">adf_scanner</mat-icon>
<mat-icon class="material-icons-outlined">adf_scanner</mat-icon>
<mat-icon class="material-icons-round">adf_scanner</mat-icon>
<mat-icon class="material-icons-sharp">adf_scanner</mat-icon>
<mat-icon class="material-icons-two-tone">adf_scanner</mat-icon>
<br>
symbols<br>outlined/+filled /rounded/+filled /sharp/+filled
<br>
<mat-icon class="material-symbols-outlined">home</mat-icon>
<mat-icon class="material-symbols-outlined-filled">home</mat-icon>
<mat-icon class="material-symbols-rounded">home</mat-icon>
<mat-icon class="material-symbols-rounded-filled">home</mat-icon>
<mat-icon class="material-symbols-sharp">home</mat-icon>
<mat-icon class="material-symbols-sharp-filled">home</mat-icon>
<br>
<mat-icon class="material-symbols-outlined">account_circle</mat-icon>
<mat-icon class="material-symbols-outlined-filled">account_circle</mat-icon>
<mat-icon class="material-symbols-rounded">account_circle</mat-icon>
<mat-icon class="material-symbols-rounded-filled">account_circle</mat-icon>
<mat-icon class="material-symbols-sharp">account_circle</mat-icon>
<mat-icon class="material-symbols-sharp-filled">account_circle</mat-icon>
<br>
<mat-icon class="material-symbols-outlined">adf_scanner</mat-icon>
<mat-icon class="material-symbols-outlined-filled">adf_scanner</mat-icon>
<mat-icon class="material-symbols-rounded">adf_scanner</mat-icon>
<mat-icon class="material-symbols-rounded-filled">adf_scanner</mat-icon>
<mat-icon class="material-symbols-sharp">adf_scanner</mat-icon>
<mat-icon class="material-symbols-sharp-filled">adf_scanner</mat-icon>
```

Answer (score 0):

I was unsatisfied that until know Google hasn't yet released their new designs as font or svg icon set. Therefore I put together a small npm package to solve the problem.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/ts-material-icons-svg

Simply import the icons you wanna use and add them to your registry. Short tutorial is in the Readme.

Cheers Marco

Answer (score 0):

Try `<span>` tag instead of `<mat-icon>` tag.

Something like this:

```
    <span class="material-icons-outlined">info</span>
```

And if you haven't already you may have to update your reference to the latest reference link:

```
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Material+Icons|Material+Icons+Outlined|Material+Icons+Two+Tone|Material+Icons+Round|Material+Icons+Sharp" rel="stylesheet">
```

I had ran into the same problem but `<span>` worked fine for me and ever since I have been using `<span>` instead of `<mat-icon>`.

Answer (score 0):

First, go to your index.html add the following line in <head>:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Material+Symbols+Outlined:opsz,wght,FILL,GRAD@20..48,100..700,0..1,-50..200"/>
```

You can also line one from [fonts.google.com/icons](https://fonts.google.com/icons) by selecting specific icon.

then write the following line of code in HTML:

```
<mat-icon class="material-symbols-outlined">delete</mat-icon>
```