# how to use outlined material icon

Tags: angular-material, material-design, google-material-icons

**Scenario :**

- I'm using material icons, and I face a problem,
   I usually use filled ones and everything is ok, 
  right now I want to use a outlined one, they have the same name, "screen_share"

**Tried Case :**

My try was include in **index.html**:

```
<link 
type="text/css" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Material+Icons" 
rel="stylesheet"/> 

<link type="text/css" 
href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons&style=outlined" 
rel="stylesheet">
```

and in **myComponent.html**

```
<button mat-button>
   <mat-icon>
      screen_share_outline
   </mat-icon>
</button>
```

but it still shows the filled one.

How can I do it?

this is not the same than the suggested duplicate, because the solution presented is the option I try and didn't work

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I get Angular Material Icon to show the outline in my Angular app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50358473/how-can-i-get-angular-material-icon-to-show-the-outline-in-my-angular-app)

Comment: See if these links are helpful  : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50358473/how-can-i-get-angular-material-icon-to-show-the-outline-in-my-angular-app , https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/11544 , https://github.com/google/material-design-icons/issues/773 , https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/issues/4164,

Comment: If no luck, download svg for that outlined icon from https://material.io/tools/icons/?icon=print_disabled&style=outline, and use it in the markup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the outlined fonts have not been finalized yet per issue #773

https://github.com/google/material-design-icons/issues/773

I see you are reviewing this issue

[How to use the new Material Design Icon themes: Outlined, Rounded, Two-Tone and Sharp?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50303454/how-to-use-the-new-material-design-icon-themes-outlined-rounded-two-tone-and)

Until the outlined versions are completely included you will need to use the workaround provided in that stackoverflow question... I verified it in stackblitz and it does work.

Add following import to index.html

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://storage.googleapis.com/non-spec-apps/mio-icons/latest/outline.css">
```

Add the following to style.css

```
.material-icons-new {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 24px;
    height: 24px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: contain;
}

.icon-white {
    webkit-filter: contrast(4) invert(1);
    -moz-filter: contrast(4) invert(1);
    -o-filter: contrast(4) invert(1);
    -ms-filter: contrast(4) invert(1);
    filter: contrast(4) invert(1);
}
```

Use the following in your component html.

```
<i class="material-icons-new outline-screen_share"></i>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
<link type="text/css" 
href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon? 
family=Material+Icons+Outlined" 
rel="stylesheet">
```

Instead of

```
<link type="text/css" 
href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon? 
family=Material+Icons&style=outlined" 
rel="stylesheet">
```

Comment: May I ask you @tobahhh where can you find that link in Google's documentation?
Thanks