# How to use Outline icons in Vuetify app?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js

```
<v-btn outline large fab color="indigo">
   <v-icon>edit</v-icon>
</v-btn>
```

In `vuetify.js` docs, the example only have outlined icons using buttons. But my requirement is to get outlined icons without using buttons.

Comment: I'll put this as related because of possible changes in the future: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50303454/how-to-use-the-new-material-design-icon-themes-outlined-rounded-two-tone-and

Comment: Looking forward more about this topic. Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it by only adding CSS.

Something like that :

**HTML**

```
<v-icon class="outlined">edit</v-icon>
```

**CSS**

```
.v-icon.outlined {
                  border: 1px solid currentColor;
                  border-radius:50%;
                  height: 56px;
                  width: 56px;
}
```

[Working CodePen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/KBzbeV)

Answer (score 1):

@Toodoo's solution above is the simplest and most effective, but for whatever reason was not working for me.

I bumped on [this](https://github.com/petergng/material-icon-font) wonderful font, derived directly from Material's, which can be very easily imported into any component:

```
<style lang="scss" scoped> 
@import '~material-icon-font/dist/Material-Icons.css';
.material-icons { font-family: 'Material Icons Outline'}
</style>
```

... and voila', no need to create any custom classes, all icons will magically by outlined (see documentation for more options, and give the guy a star!)

Answer (score 1):

First, make sure to download Material Design Icons (including Outlined) in your `index.html` file:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Material+Icons|Material+Icons+Outlined" />
```

Now, you can use Outlined icons by simply adding `material-icons-outlined` class to your `v-icon`'s.

**Example:**

```
<v-icon class="material-icons-outlined">
  file_upload
</v-icon>
```

In case you need to use an outlined icon in your `:prepend-icon`, `:append-icon`, etc. use a corresponding slot:

```
<v-autocomplete
  ...
>
  <template v-slot:prepend>
    <v-icon class="material-icons-outlined">
      file_upload
    </v-icon>
  </template>
</v-autocomplete>
```

The latter works with pretty much all kinds of form inputs in Vuetify.

Answer (score 0):

```
<v-icon>
   mdi-calendar-month-outline
</v-icon>
```

Add "-outline" to icon name