# Material Icons Rounded not working with Internet Explorer 11

Tags: css, internet-explorer, google-material-icons

I'm trying to use [Rounded Material Icons](https://material.io/tools/icons/?style=round) but it appears that Internet Explorer isn't having it.  It'll display regular material icons, but not the rounded ones.  It doesn't display anything at all, just blank.

NOTE: You'll have to view this page in IE to see the issue. (sorry)

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons+Round"
          rel="stylesheet">
          
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons"
          rel="stylesheet">

This works
<i class="material-icons">
delete_forever
</i>

This does not
<i class="material-icons-round">
delete_forever
</i>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In IE11 only Filled theme icons Visible and other themes(**Outlined, Rounded, Two-Tone, Sharp**) not visible. But when you open https://material.io/tools/icons/ in your **IE11 browser** all themes icons working fine.

Because Google use different **stylesheets** for all theme icons on there demo page https://material.io/tools/icons/.

```
Outlined:
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://storage.googleapis.com/non-spec-apps/mio-icons/latest/outline.css">

Rounded:
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://storage.googleapis.com/non-spec-apps/mio-icons/latest/round.css">

Two-Tone:
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://storage.googleapis.com/non-spec-apps/mio-icons/latest/twotone.css">

Sharp:
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://storage.googleapis.com/non-spec-apps/mio-icons/latest/sharp.css">
```

> **So how we suppose to show Rounded Theme icons on IE11 - It's very Simple**

**Step 1:** Just Add below **stylesheet** in your code.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://storage.googleapis.com/non-spec-apps/mio-icons/latest/round.css">
```

**Step 2:** if you want to show `delete_forever` icon just add `round-` before `delete_forever` and use as a class.

```
<i class="round-delete_forever"></i>
```

**Step 3:** You have to write few styling for it, i just create new class `mat-custom-icon`, write styling and add in `<i class="round-delete_forever mat-custom-icon"></i>`

```
.mat-custom-icon {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 24px;
    height: 24px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: contain;
}
```

Below code snippet have all mentioned fixes. Try this I hope it'll help you out. Thanks

```css
.mat-custom-icon {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 24px;
  height: 24px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons+Round" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://storage.googleapis.com/non-spec-apps/mio-icons/latest/round.css">

This works
<i class="material-icons">
delete_forever
</i>

This does not
<i class="material-icons-round">
delete_forever
</i>

This will work on IE11
<i class="round-delete_forever mat-custom-icon"></i>
```

Answer (score 0):

I reproduce this problem in my side and I find a workaround to solve this. I found it in the most voted answer of a [related thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50303454/how-to-use-the-new-material-design-icon-themes-outlined-rounded-two-tone-and). I also made a demo and it can run well in IE11.

```css
.material-icons-new {
            display: inline-block;
            width: 24px;
            height: 24px;
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            background-size: contain;
        }

        .icon-white {
            webkit-filter: contrast(4) invert(1);
            -moz-filter: contrast(4) invert(1);
            -o-filter: contrast(4) invert(1);
            -ms-filter: contrast(4) invert(1);
            filter: contrast(4) invert(1);
        }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://storage.googleapis.com/non-spec-apps/mio-icons/latest/round.css">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Material+Icons|Material+Icons+Outlined|Material+Icons+Two+Tone|Material+Icons+Round|Material+Icons+Sharp" rel="stylesheet">

This works
<i class="material-icons">
delete_forever
</i>
This does not
<i class="material-icons-new round-delete_forever">
</i>
```