# Material Icon Two-Tone: How to change the color of icon?

Tags: html, css, angular-material, material-design

I use the material icon in my Angular app, and I want to use the two-tone icon.
How can I change the color of the icon?
I tried with the classic color: red; in my CSS file but doesn't work.
Can you help me, please?

[Here are a Stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-icon-3ksyuu)

Comment: Can you paste you code or create a fiddle?

Answer (score 13):

Following this [Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50303454/how-to-use-the-new-material-design-icon-themes-outlined-rounded-two-tone-and/54902967) you can use the `color` css key except for materials two tone theme which seems to be glitchy ;-)

A workaround is described in one of several angular material github [issue](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-web-react/issues/730)'s by using a custom css filter. This custom filter can be generated [here](https://codepen.io/sosuke/pen/Pjoqqp).

E.g.:

Html:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Material+Icons|Material+Icons+Outlined|Material+Icons+Round|Material+Icons+Two+Tone|Material+Icons+Sharp">

<i class="material-icons-two-tone  red">home</i>
```

css:

```
.red {
filter: invert(8%) sepia(94%) saturate(4590%) hue-rotate(358deg) brightness(101%) contrast(112%);
}
```

Attachments:

- Working Angular [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-icon-afckgh?file=index.html)
- [Codepen example](https://codepen.io/themau5/pen/QWwaYKR)
- [Codepen CSS filter Generator](https://codepen.io/sosuke/pen/Pjoqqp)

Comment: It seems this is even what Google does in fonts.google.com/icons! Inspector shows they apply `filter: contrast(4) invert(1);`

Comment: The latest comment on https://github.com/material-components/material-components-web-react/issues/730#issuecomment-1071052873 worked best for me!