# I am trying to fill color in flag icon on hovering

Tags: css, angular, angular-material

I have tried this. But It does not get filled on hovering.

```css
.flag-icon
{
  fill:white;
}

.flag-icon:hover
{
  fill:red;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500,700,400italic|Roboto+Mono:400,500|Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">

<span class="material-icons flag-icon">outline_flag</span>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `color` instead of `fill`.

See the snippet bellow:

```css
.flag-icon{
  color:blue;
}
.flag-icon:hover{
  color:red
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500,700,400italic|Roboto+Mono:400,500|Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">

<span class="material-icons flag-icon">outline_flag</span>
```

**Edit** - Filled x outlined icons.

To have the outlined style one must add the class `material-icons-outlined`.

If you want to change from a outlined icon to a filled icon on hover, you may use the following code that relies on a simples jquery script:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.flag-icon').hover(function(){
    $(this).removeClass('material-icons-outlined');
  }, function(){
    $(this).addClass('material-icons-outlined');
  });
});
```

```css
.flag-icon:hover{
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Material+Icons|Material+Icons+Outlined|Material+Icons+Sharp|Material+Icons+Round|Material+Icons+Two+Tone" rel="stylesheet">

<span class="flag-icon material-icons material-icons-outlined">flag</span>
```

Take a look at this question for more examples:
[How to use the new Material Design Icon themes: Outlined, Rounded, Two-Tone and Sharp?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50303454/how-to-use-the-new-material-design-icon-themes-outlined-rounded-two-tone-and)

Comment: It will change the color of outlined flag . I want to change the outlined flag into fill flag

Comment: i added a new code for changing from outlined into filled flag

Answer (score 0):

```
.flag-icon::before {
        font-size: 18px;
        margin-top: 5px;
        font-family: "Material Icons";
        transition: 0.1s ease;
        content: 'outlined_flag';
    }
    
    .flag-icon:hover::before {
        content: "flag";
        color: red;
    }
```