# How to use rounded icons in vuetify tag <v-icon></v-icon>?

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I want to use rounded material icons within the v-icon tag which comes with vuetify.
I tried everything on stackoverflow...

```
<v-icon>announcement</v-icon>
```

Comment: Why not `<v-icon class="icon-rounded>` and `.icon-rounded { border-radius: 50%; }`? For that you probably have to move "announcement" out of `<v-icon>`

Comment: What exactly is a "rounded icon"? Maybe you are looking for rounded icon buttons https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/buttons or maybe rounded chip with an icon https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/chips ?

Comment: With the v-icon tag I'm using material icons by google. There is a certain style called rounded I can add. With v-icon I'm using the regular ones. Within the tags the icon is inserted called by its name. https://material.io/resources/icons/?style=round

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned here : [How to use the new Material Design Icon themes: Outlined, Rounded, Two-Tone and Sharp?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50303454/how-to-use-the-new-material-design-icon-themes-outlined-rounded-two-tone-and/54902967)

You can add the Material+Icons+Round font family in your index.html file :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Material+Icons|Material+Icons+Round">
```

You can now make your icons rounded by adding the class 'material-icons-round' to your v-icon :

```
<v-icon class='material-icons-round'>east</v-icon>
```

Just tried it with Vuejs 2.x and Last available version of Vuetify - as of dec. 2020 - and it's pretty straightforward! Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks mate that's the solution! :)

Answer (score 0):

Use `v-btn` with the `fab` property

Comment: The fab property only transforms the button into a circle which I can also achieve with the icon prop for v-btn.