# Google material icon CDN is not working in NEXTJS

Tags: next.js, cdn, google-fonts

I added the google icon CDN to my _document.js file nextJs project, but still google icons are not working in my project.

````
```import { Html, Head, Main, NextScript } from "next/document";
   export default function Document() {
   return (
   <Html>
    <Head>
     <link
      href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons"
      rel="stylesheet"
     />
    </Head>
     <body>
      <Main />

      <NextScript />
    </body>
  </Html>
````

);
}

Comment: Check this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50303454/how-to-use-the-new-material-design-icon-themes-outlined-rounded-two-tone-and

Answer (score 3):

Inltall the material-icons library in node

```
npm i material-icons@latest
```

Import it to your project

```
import 'material-icons/iconfont/material-icons.css'
```

Then you should be able to simply use the `<span>icon</span>` you need

For more details see https://www.npmjs.com/package/material-icons